# .Net - Moving from System.Xml to Saxon.Api performance issues

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, saxon

I have written a C# application to parse very large (100MB+) XML files.

The way I accomplished it was that I traverse through the file using a `System.Xml.XmlReader` and then, once I get to the final nodes I need to collect values from, I convert each of those very small elements into a `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` and perform various XPath statements via `XEelement.XPathEvaluate` to get the data I need.

This worked very well and efficiently, but I hit a snag where I was sometimes getting bad data due to the fact that `XPathEvaluate` only supports XPath 1.0 and my statements were XPath 2.0 (question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49157805/1693085)).

My code for originally doing this looks somewhat as follows:

```
void parseNode_Old(XmlReader rdr, List<string> xPathsToExtract)
{
    // Enter the node:
    rdr.Read();

    // Load it as an XElement so as to be able to evaluate XPaths:
    var nd = XElement.Load(rdr);

    // Loop through the XPaths related to that node and evaluate them:
    foreach (var xPath in xPathsToExtract)
    {
        var xPathVal = nd.XPathEvaluate(xPath);

        // Do whatever with the extracted value(s)
    }
}
```

Following the suggestions given in my previous question, I decided the best solution would be to move from `System.Xml` to `Saxon.Api` (which does support XPath 2.0) and my current updated code looks as follows:

```
void parseNode_Saxon(XmlReader rdr, List<string> xPathsToExtract)
{
    // Set up the Saxon XPath processors:
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    XPathCompiler compiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();
    XdmNode nd = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(rdr);

    // Loop through the XPaths related to that node and evaluate them:
    foreach (var xPath in xPathsToExtract)
    {
        var xPathVal = compiler.EvaluateSingle(xPath, (XdmNode)childNode);

        // Do whatever with the extracted value(s)
    }
}
```

This is working (with a few other changes to my XPaths), but it has become about 5-10 times slower.

This is my first time working with the Saxon.Api library and this is what I came up with. I'm hoping there's a better way to accomplish this to make the code-execution speed comparable or, if anyone has other ideas on how to evaluate XPath 2.0 statements in a better way without a substantial re-write, I'd love to hear them!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

**UPDATE:**

In trying to fix this myself, I moved the following 2 statements to my constructor:

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
XPathCompiler compiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();
```

as opposed to constantly re-create them with each call to this method which has helped substantially, but the process is still about 3 times slower than the native `System.Xml.Linq` version. Any other ideas / thoughts on ways to implement this parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the best you can do with this set-up.

Saxon on .NET is often 3-5 times slower that Saxon on Java, for reasons which we have never got to the bottom of. We're currently exploring the possibility of rebuilding it using Excelsior JET rather than IKVMC to see if this can speed things up.

Saxon is much slower on a third-party DOM implementation than on its own native tree representation, but it seems you have changed your code to use the native tree model.

Since you're parsing each XPath expression every time it is executed, your performance may be dominated by XPath compilation time (even if you're searching a large XML document). Until recently Saxon's compile-time performance received very little attention, since we reckoned that doing more work at compile time to save effort at run-time was always worthwhile; but in this kind of scenario this clearly isn't the case. It may be worth splitting the compile and run-time and measuring both separately, just to see if that gives any insights. It might suggest, for example, switching off some of the optimization options. Obviously if you can cache and reuse compiled XPath expressions that will help.

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael, I was hoping there was just a glitch in my coding... Such a pity since it is such a deep library to be able to use. For this specific project, it just may make the most sense to use a different one, though. Tanks again!!!